# How to check for 3 in a row in tic tac toe game

Tags: python

I am making a tic tac toe game and trying to create a function that checks if 3 of the same spots in a row have the same input 'x' or '0'.  I am having trouble with the three_in_row function I am trying to make to trigger game over.  I am trying to figure out how to do this in a simple way so all rows or columns will be triggers if 3 X's or 0's are played... Here's what I have so far. This is in python 2.7.13

(this is only part of the code I think should be relevant)

```
def setup_board(size): 
    board = []
    for row in range(size):
        board.append([])
        for col in range(size):
            board[row].append(empty)
    return board 

def three_in_row(b):      
    b[0][0] and b[0][1] and b[0][2] == 'x'

def game_over(b):
    if three_in_row(b) == True:
        print "Congratulations You Win!"
    else:
        return False

def tic_tac_toe():
    b = setup_board(3)
    run_game(b)
```

Comment: `and` doesn't chain like that. `if b[0][0] == b[0][1] == b[0][2] == 'x'` would do what you are expecting.

Comment: I would suggest you make if and ifelse statements in order to check all possible scenarios and to return if any of the winning outcomes match, if statements are not too costly in python if i recall correctly so your program shouldn't suffer in speed. That should also make the code easily readable, which is the king principle in python

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it might make more sense to store X's as +1 and O's as -1, so that you can easily do arithmetic to check if the game is over.

For example:

```
def three_in_row(b):
    xWin = check_winner(b,3)
    oWin = check_winner(b,-3)
    return xWin | oWin

def check_winner(b, valToCheck):
    foundWin = any(sum(r) in {valToCheck} for r in b)  # check rows
    # now check columns
    for i in range(3):
        foundWin = foundWin | (sum([b[j][i] for j in range(3)]) == valToCheck)
    # now check diagonals
    foundWin = foundWin | (sum([b[i][i] for i in range(3)]) == valToCheck)
    foundWin = foundWin | (sum([b[i][2-i] for i in range(3)]) == valToCheck)
    return foundWin
```

Thanks to Blender for the following more succinct method:

```
def three_in_row(b):
    return any(sum(r) in {3, -3} for r in b)
```

Comment: `any(sum(r) in {3, -3} for r in b)` is a little cleaner.

Comment: Nice, I like that! I will add to the answer.

Comment: Does this solution check for diagonals?

Comment: No, this only checks rows as per the OP original question. It does not check columns or diagonals

Comment: "three in a row" in the case does not refer to just rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
def line_match(game):
    for i in range(3):
        set_r = set(game[i])
        if len(set_r) == 1 and game[i][0] != 0:
            return game[i][0]
    return 0
#transposed column function for future use
#def column(game):
#   trans = numpy.transpose(game)
#   for i in range(3):
#       set_r = set(trans[i])
#       if len(set_r) == 1 and trans[i][0] != 0:
#           return list(set_r)[0]

def diagonal_match(game):
    if game[1][1] != 0:
        if game[1][1] == game[0][0] == game[2][2]: 
            return game[1][1]
        elif game[1][1] == game[0][2] == game[2][0]:
            return game[1][1]           
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for the checks is either:

```
b[0][0] == 'x' and  b[0][1] == 'x' and b[0][2] == 'x'
```

or (more succinctly):

```
b[0][0] == b[0][1] == b[0][2] == 'x'
```

You are also missing a *return* just before your check, like:

```
return b[0][0] == b[0][1] == b[0][2] == 'x'
```

Anyways, your code does not iterate over all the rows. A possible correction would be:

```
def three_in_row(b):
    for row in rage(0, 3):
        if b[row][0] == b[row][1] == b[row][2] == 'x':
            return True
    return False
```

Doing a three_in_column(b) should be fairly easy (changing b[row][n] in b[n][column]), so is also manually checking the two diagonals.